# How do I set the creation time of a file?

Tags: command-line, uti

I have a script that converts a file to another format, and I want the resulting file to have the same timestamps as the original, including the creation time (as shown by `ls -lU`).

I can use touch to set the access and modification time, but I don't see a way to set the creation time.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
touch -t YYYYMMDDhhmm file.ext
```

This will set the modification and creation dates of a file. I ran it on a file I created this morning, and here's what Get Info says:

[image]

Comment: I should of course have tested this first :-) Thanks

Comment: Nathan, did the file exist before you "touched" it? `touch` doesn't change creation dates unless it creates the file itself.

Comment: -1 `touch` will only set the creation date of a file if it creates the file, _or if the new date is earlier than the file's creation date_. (It's impossible to have a file whose modification date is earlier than its creation date.) So this solution does not work if the new date is later than the file's creation date. The `SetFile` solution will always work.

Answer (score 5):

SetFile can also be used to set the creation date before the modification date or in the future.

```
-d date    Sets the creation date, where date is a string of the
           form: "mm/dd/[yy]yy [hh:mm:[:ss] [AM | PM]]" Notes:
           Enclose the string in quotation marks if it contains spa-
           ces. The date must be in the Unix epoch, that is, between
           1/1/1970 and 1/18/2038. If the year is provided as a two-
           digit year, it is assumed to be in the 21st century and
           must be from 00 (2000) through 38 (2038).
```

This would set the creation date to the modification date:

```
SetFile -d "$(GetFileInfo -m test.txt)" test.txt
```

SetFile and GetFileInfo are part of the command line tools package, which can be downloaded from [developer.apple.com/downloads](https://developer.apple.com/downloads/) or from Xcode's preferences after installing it from the App Store.