# How to change the creation (st_birthtime) date/time of a file in Lion?

Tags: command-line, uti

`touch(1)` can only change **modification** and **access** times, but has no options for **creation** time. [This](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/16824/how-do-i-set-the-creation-time-of-a-file) does not work, at least not on Lion.

So how do I change the **creation** time, also referred to as **birthtime** in `fstat(2)`? There's no corresponding call in `utimes(2)` and there doesn't seem to be any command line tool for this.

I know I can copy the file to a new file, which then gets the current time as birthtime (and then delete the original), but surely there must be a better way?

Comment: `touch -t yyyymmddhhmm $file` does seem to change the creation date, but only if it's before the original creation date.

Comment: Good point, @Lri - that actually makes sense, since that updates the mtime and atime and a file couldn't be accessed or modified before it was created. But it doesn't let me set a newer creation time.

Comment: Are you referring to changing it via the command line, or just in general, not necessarily with the CLI?

Comment: Frankly I would hope you *can't* change it, as surely it would defeat the entire point of the field?! Also I suspect some of hte problem is that birthtime/creation time isn't a standard filesystem feature; hfs added it in their extended attributes, I think - so unless utilities have been updated to recognise that, they won't be able to do much with it.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`touch -t` also changes the creation time if the target modification time is before the original creation time.

SetFile can set the creation time to be before the modification time or in the future.

```
-d date    Sets the creation date, where date is a string of the
           form: "mm/dd/[yy]yy [hh:mm:[:ss] [AM | PM]]" Notes:
           Enclose the string in quotation marks if it contains spa-
           ces. The date must be in the Unix epoch, that is, between
           1/1/1970 and 1/18/2038. If the year is provided as a two-
           digit year, it is assumed to be in the 21st century and
           must be from 00 (2000) through 38 (2038).
```

This would set the creation time to the modification time:

```
SetFile -d "$(GetFileInfo -m test.txt)" test.txt
```

SetFile and GetFileInfo are part of the command line tools package, which can be downloaded from Xcode's preferences or [developer.apple.com/downloads](https://developer.apple.com/downloads/).

Comment: Strictly speaking "birthtime" (`crtime`) and `ctime `  are different things (see [File creation times in ZFS](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29906359/how-can-i-set-file-creation-times-in-zfs/)

Comment: Of course access and modification times are often the same - but for different reasons. The [`touch`](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Darwin/Reference/ManPages/man1/touch.1.html) and [`stat`](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Darwin/Reference/ManPages/man1/stat.1.html)  manual pages have the details. I'd be interested to know how OpenZFS for OSX as well as the OSX "native" filesystems handle `crtime` field or what `stat` reports for the `crtime` on various versions of OSX.

Answer (score -1):

Try:

```
cat filename > newfile
mv filename ~/.Trash/
mv newfile filename
```

That should work.

Comment: You'll still need to delete the original. Ingmar had already covered this.

Comment: Whoops, should've read better. But no, there is not a better way...