# Change Date Created based on the filename

Tags: mac, applescript, command-line

I've downloaded a bunch of my Instagram images but the Date Created of the files is set to the time that I initiated the download. What I do have though is the Date Created in the filename. What I want to do is take the date in the filename, which I've changed to YYYYMMDDhhmm, and set that as the creation date of each file.

I changed the date in the filename into the YYYYMMDDhhmm because this is the format that the `touch -t` command likes. Now all I need is a way to take the first 12 characters of the filename, pass it to `touch -t` as the date to touch the file with and follow that with the full filename.

I imagine this could be accomplished with a combination of Hazel and a shell/AppleScript so that the date could be passed on from each individual image.

Cheers for any help :)

Comment: Now if only `touch -t` would change the creation date, see http://apple.stackexchange.com/q/49154/9058 ... Do you want to change the creation or the modification date? Both is possible, but the solution is different.

Comment: The creation date. In my manual tests, if i was to type `touch -t 201010201000 /Users/smithjw/Dropbox/Extracted/instagram/test/201010201000\ 1287551285.jpg` the creation date would be modified.

Comment: That's the modification date, see `man touch`. Use `ls -lU` to display the creation date.

Comment: Well I don't know what was happening on my system but it changed the creation date, as well as the modification date, when I used `touch -t`

Comment: What exactly do the file names look like? Is it just the date? Is the date first and followed by a space? A dash? Are they at the end?

Comment: The filenames are all like this `201010301000 1288442222.jpg`, where the first 12 characters are the date/time

Comment: Have a look at [basename](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Darwin/Reference/ManPages/man1/basename.1.html). You could use it to strip the file name down to what you need.

Answer (score 1):

So after some hunting I stumbled on this little AppleScript on Mac OS X Hints. Thanks [Krioni](http://hints.macworld.com/users.php?mode=profile&uid=1253)! I'm sure with some tinkering I could modify it to work with my filenames, but I just batch edited the image filenames to fit in with the script.

```
on open files_
    repeat with file_ in files_
        tell application "Finder"
            set file_name to name of file_
            set od to AppleScript's text item delimiters
            set AppleScript's text item delimiters to {"_"}
            set new_creation_date to second text item of file_name
            set new_creation_date to new_creation_date & "1000"
            set file_ to POSIX path of file_
            do shell script "touch -t " & new_creation_date & " " & quoted form of file_
            set AppleScript's text item delimiters to od
        end tell
    end repeat
end open
```

It simply looks for the second text item of the filename in between underscores and uses that as the date. It then adds `"1000"` as the time to the `touch` command. Hopefully this will help someone else out there.

The original thread can be found [here](http://hints.macworld.com/article.php?story=20060703160750583).

Answer (score 1):

`touch -t` only changes the creation date if the target (modification) date is before the original creation date.

`for f in *.jpg; do touch -t ${f% *} "$f" && mv "$f" "${f#* }"; done`

`SetFile -d` always changes the creation date.

```
-d date    Sets the creation date, where date is a string of the
           form: "mm/dd/[yy]yy [hh:mm:[:ss] [AM | PM]]"
```

`for f in *.jpg; do date=$(printf %s "$f" | sed -E 's|^(....)(..)(..)(..)(..).*|\2/\3/\1/ \4:\5|'); SetFile -m "$date" -d "$date" "$f" && mv "$f" "${f#* }"; done`

SetFile is part of the command line tools package which can be downloaded from [developer.apple.com/downloads](https://developer.apple.com/downloads/) or Xcode's preferences.