# How to create a file with a specific Created at time?

Tags: uti

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How do I set the creation time of a file?](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/16824/how-do-i-set-the-creation-time-of-a-file)

How can you create a files on a Mac that have a specific creation date (different from the current one)?

What I have found so far, [touch](http://www.mkssoftware.com/docs/man1/touch.1.asp) can only alter the modified at time...

Comment: [How to change the creation date/time of a file in Lion?](http://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/49154/how-to-change-the-creation-date-time-of-a-file-in-lion) only mentions `touch -t` as well.

Comment: @Lri, thank you: I didn't come across it in my searches.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe you can do it with [touch](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Darwin/Reference/ManPages/man1/touch.1.html).

```
touch -t YYYYMMDDhhmm /filehere
```

Comment: `touch -t` normally only changes the modification date. The creation date is only changed if the new modification date would be before it.

Comment: On 10.7, touch -t appears to work on my test system, even if the mod date is after.  I used touch -mt to change the mod time and it works fine.

Comment: I meant that `touch file.txt; touch -t 199901010000 file.txt` would change the creation date, but `touch file2.txt; touch -t 209901010000 file2.txt` wouldn't.

Answer (score 4):

SetFile can also be used to set the creation date before the modification date or in the future.

```
-d date    Sets the creation date, where date is a string of the
           form: "mm/dd/[yy]yy [hh:mm:[:ss] [AM | PM]]" Notes:
           Enclose the string in quotation marks if it contains spa-
           ces. The date must be in the Unix epoch, that is, between
           1/1/1970 and 1/18/2038. If the year is provided as a two-
           digit year, it is assumed to be in the 21st century and
           must be from 00 (2000) through 38 (2038).
```

This would set the creation date to the modification date:

```
SetFile -d "$(GetFileInfo -m test.txt)" test.txt
```

SetFile and GetFileInfo are part of the command line tools package, which can be downloaded from [developer.apple.com/downloads](https://developer.apple.com/downloads/) or from Xcode's preferences after installing it from the App Store.